# ZIP save as weird text as type in windows

Tags: windows, save-as

When i try to download a zip file and click on save as the following weird text appear in the select box.

[image: weird text]

I can change all files or this, the file is ok when saved, but what can be this, how can i fix this?

Comment: Which browser? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: or if you are not using the phpmyadmin site, try change the source where you download from...[try this location](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/5.0.4/)

Comment: @harrymc It's only in chrome and edge, in firefox i can't see this dialog box.

Comment: How are you downloading the file? Can you give an example website?

Comment: @harrymc https://www.learningcontainer.com/sample-zip-files/, download button, then on the download tab click save as (edge://downloads/all)

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem - the Download button starts the standard Save dialog. Try running Chrome in Incognito mode, and if it works then the problem is with an extension. Otherwise, I would say to uninstall Chrome, scrub its folders and re-install.